# Embedding "Dolby Digital Plus with Dolby Atmos" into MP4 using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, dolby

How can I encode Dolby Atmos into MP4? I am using this command `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i input.ec3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a copy -disposition:a default -metadata:s:a:0 complexity_index=16 -metadata:s:a:0 title="Dolby Atmos" output_test.mp4` I have to provide every single piece of data that is inside this EC3 file. I have noticed that when I am running this command the MP4 file contains actual Dolby Atmos stream but it's missing complexity index. Raw EC3 file has Complexity Index set to 16 but after adding it to MP4 file the complexity index is not present and this MP4 is not identified as a video with proper Dolby Atmos stream

I thought that after using this command, complexity index will be added correctly. I don't want to use MKV but it looks like I will have to do that.